# append PHP code to HTML input placeholder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to append a PHP function that shows the user his/her IP within an inputs' placeholder. I've never seen anything like this been done before so I'd like to just see if it's possible or not.

My thoughts right now is to do something along these lines:

```
$('input').attr(placeholder,function(){
$('input').append('<?php $variable ?>');
});
```

then run the PHP code through here some how. If someone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful!

Comment: You can add `echo` before `$variable` and it will output that content. The PHP won't be accessible once the page has loaded though. e.g. if `$variable` is dynamic, it won't be with this approach, you'll need ajax for that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add this to the html when you echo the element? In fact why wouldn't you set the value itself? Dynamic placeholder doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: Is there a need for jQuery? Why can't you just add `<? echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>` within the input fields `value` value?

Comment: @the_pete Becuase i'm using a placeholder and not a value field. If I use placeholder there's a lot of other stuff that will break on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP you can make a function to retrieve the IP of the user then echo the script in your page:

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

    $('input').attr(placeholder,function(){
    $('input').append('".getUserIP()."');
    });
    </script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`$('#inputID').attr("placeholder","<?php echo $variable; ?>");`

And if you want to append to all inputs:

`$(":input").attr("placeholder","<?php echo $variable; ?>");`
should do the work